# Flask main.css file not working with base.html file

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm relatively new to Flask and I'm trying to get my main.ss file to interact with my base.html file. When I make the changes to the CSS code it's not reflected when I view the application in the browser. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The filepath to base.html is documents/ds/ds/templates/base.html
The filepath to main.css is documents/ds/ds/static/main.css

The title base.html code reads:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

  <title> Deplorable Snowflake </title>

  <link href="/static/main.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter- 
  bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
  media="screen">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter- 
  bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='moment.min.js') }}"> 
  </script>
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" 

src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"> 
</script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


</head>
```

Is it the way i'm linking to it in the header? ...

Answer (score 0):

Change `<link href="/static/main.css" rel="stylesheet">`

to:

```
<link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and make sure the `main.css` file is placed in your static folder.